# In Ag-Grid, Is it possible to style rows based on external data?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm trying to style a row based on an external value in the parent of grid. I've tried using `getRowClass` and `rowClassRules` but I don't seem to have access to any data that isn't directly inside of the `params` value provided. Will I have to add the value of state I'm trying to access to `params`?

For example, here is something similar to what I'm trying to do:

```
getRowClass: params => {
  if (params.data.id === MAIN_ITEM_ID) return 'selected-border';
  else if (SELECTED_ITEM_IDS.includes(params.data.id)) return 'selected';
}
```

The `MAIN_ITEM_ID` and `SELECTED_ITEM_IDS` are being set/updated whenever the `onSelectionChanged` function is run. And I the item that matches ID within `MAIN_ITEM_ID` to have a border and the other selected rows (`SELECTED_ITEM_IDS`) will just have a normal colored background

Comment: @NearHuscarl yeah I think that's exactly what I'm looking for. It's funny I've spent a long time looking through their docs but don't remember seeing anything on `context`. Thanks!